# Small DSL: Converting JSON to MSSQL query

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, t-sql, dsl

#### Scenario

Once upon a time, there was this human (*ahem, me, ahem*) who tried (and succeeded) to build a small program which would convert JSON to a MSSQL query using Python 3.x.

---

#### How does it work?

The user makes a POST request with a JSON (in the code, I've used a JSON file) which looks like this:

```
{
  "endpoint": "rfc",
  "expression": [
    {
      "field": "first_name",
      "operator": "EQ",
      "value": "Dixie"
    },
    "AND",
    [
      {
        "field": "last_name",
        "operator": "NEQ",
        "value": "Smith"
      },
      "OR",
      {
        "field": "middle_name",
        "operator": "EQ",
        "value": "Sam"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "limit": "2"
}
```

Now, the key point in this story is the `expression` which is being translated to a query, using recursion, as follows:

```
def process(data):
    """
    :param data: JSON Object (dict).
    :return: where clause (str) built from data
    """
    where_clause = ""
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for part in data:
            if part not in LOGICAL_OPERATORS:
                where_clause += " ({}) ".format(process(part))
            else:
                where_clause += process(part)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        where_clause += " {} {} '{}'".format(data["field"], COMPARISON_OPERATORS[data["operator"]], data["value"])
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        return data
    return where_clause
```

The entire code, is as follows:

```
import json

LOGICAL_OPERATORS = ("AND", "OR")

COMPARISON_OPERATORS = {
    "LT": "<",
    "GT": ">",
    "LTE": "<=",
    "GTE": ">=",
    "EQ": "=",
    "NEQ": "!="
}


def get_data(file):
    """
    :param file: JSON file.
    :return: data as a json object (dict).
    """
    with open(file) as data_file:
        return json.load(data_file)


def process(data):
    """
    :param data: JSON Object (dict).
    :return: where clause (str) built from data
    """
    where_clause = ""
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for part in data:
            if part not in LOGICAL_OPERATORS:
                where_clause += " ({}) ".format(process(part))
            else:
                where_clause += process(part)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        where_clause += " {} {} '{}'".format(data["field"], COMPARISON_OPERATORS[data["operator"]], data["value"])
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        return data
    return where_clause


def main():
    expression = get_data("other.json")["expression"]
    where_clause = process(expression)

    return "SELECT * FROM table WHERE {}".format(where_clause)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

---

#### Questions:

- Will the recursive function scale good on a larger `expression`? Now, that `expression` can go in depth as long as the memory goes. Should I add a limit to it?
- Did I miss something? Maybe an edge case?
- Is there an already builtin in out there for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Escaping and SQL injections

One of the major problems in the presented code is that the code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and does not properly sanitize, validate and escape the field values.

For example, if a `last_name` contains a single quote, for example `O'Reilly`:

```
{
    "field": "last_name",
    "operator": "NEQ",
    "value": "O'Reilly"
},
```

The generated query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  ( first_name = 'Dixie') AND ( ( last_name != 'O'Reilly') OR ( middle_name = 'Sam') )
```

which is *syntactically incorrect query* and would raise an error if executed (which may be a sign of not properly sanitized inputs for a potential "bad" user).

Then, we can try:

```
{
  "endpoint": "rfc",
  "expression": [
    {
      "field": "first_name",
      "operator": "EQ",
      "value": "' or '1' = '1"
    }
  ],
  "limit": "2"
}
```

which will result into:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  ( first_name = '' or '1' = '1')
```

which will match everything in the table.

#### Possible to solution to the problem

A possible solution to the problem would be to use *parameterized queries* and named placeholders where names would come from the `field` parameter (assuming it's unique). Something along these lines (please test thoroughly):

```
def process(data, parameters={}):
    """
    :param data: JSON Object (dict). 
    :param parameters: dict.
    :return: where clause (str) built from data
    """
    where_clause = ""
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for part in data:
            if part not in LOGICAL_OPERATORS:
                where_clause += " ({}) ".format(process(part, parameters))
            else:
                where_clause += process(part, parameters)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        where_clause += " {} {} %({})s ".format(data["field"], COMPARISON_OPERATORS[data["operator"]], data["field"])
        parameters[data["field"]] = data["value"]
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        return data
    return where_clause


def main():
    expression = get_data("other.json")["expression"]
    parameters = {}
    where_clause = process(expression, parameters)

    return "SELECT * FROM table WHERE {}".format(where_clause), parameters
```

---

> Is there an already builtin in out there for this?

I would look into using ORMs like [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to generate queries. This way you would not have to deal with SQL at all, working with Python abstraction layer only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Due to the deep _nestedness_ of the `expression` I'll have to build the entire `where` clause at once, so the recursive function is somewhat mandatory when building it. I thought of using a parametrised query: `"""SELECT * FROM table WHERE %s""", (where_clause,)`. Won't that sanitise my query? More, I'm already using Django and this is just a backend logic. Adding SQLAlchemy is not really an option, unfortunately :(

Comment: @Cajuu' yup, parameterized queries are usually the way to go when inserting parameters into a query. You would need to keep track of placeholders..you should probably use named placeholders like `%(firstname)s` and then parameterize with a dictionary `{'firstname': 'John'}`. Thanks.

Comment: Mmm, sounds like it might work. Could you please expand in your answer on the last point ? (the one about placeholders) and how you'd do it.

Comment: @MrGrj sure, updated the answer with a possible solution. Don't really like passing a mutable `parameters` argument, but works for a couple of samples, this needs tests, of course. Thanks.